# Fixture present but not loading

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm loading a fixture with `loadFixtures('frontend.html');`. According to my console the fixture is loaded: `XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:4567/spec/javascripts/fixtures/frontend.html?_=1389008650540".`

However; the fixture is nowhere to be seen? I can't see it when I inspect my code. Divs I'm trying to find with jasmine-jquery all fail.

I'm assuming it's not appending or something. What to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you resolved this please post it here.  I'm having similar problems when I use Jasmine 2.0 and jasmine-jquery 2.0.2. per this question I posted today [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763470/jasmine-jquery-loadfixtures-with-jasmine-2-0-wont-work)

Comment: I believe I've fixed it, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it was. It wasn't a typo I believe, but a config-error.