# jasmine getFixtures is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm developing some unitTests using Jasmine. I'm currently working on Windows8.1 and when I run my test I get following error message.

> TypeError: jasmine.getFixtures() is not a function

This is the code that I'm using. I don't know what I must change in order to do this work.

Karma.conf.js

```
//More configuration entries
 ...........
  files: [
// app-specific code
'src/app/app.js',

// 3rd-party resources
'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',

// test files
'test/unit/**/*.js',

//fixture to serve mockData in Tests
{ pattern: 'test/unit/mock-data/*.json' }
]
```

Here is the piece of code from my test.

```
it('Should load my fixture', function(){
    jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'HpIpsUi/test/unit/mock-data';
    var json = readFixtures('diagnostics.json');
    var result = JSON.parse(json);
    expect(result).toBeDefined();1
})
```

It's not recognizing my call to the function jasmine.getFictures().

Thank you for your help

Comment: Which version of jasmine are you using? I wonder if this post is relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763470/jasmine-jquery-loadfixtures-with-jasmine-2-0-wont-work

Comment: Hi @doctorlove I'm using version 2.4.1 I'm going to read that thread carefully but I already tried different similars things and it didn't work

Answer (score 3):

Have you included the jasmine-query library? It's defined there, not in the jasmine library.

> Said `jasmine-query.js` needs to be downloaded, and added as file, because it's not installable with `npm` yet.